# Java PDFBox list all named destinations of a page

Tags: java, pdf, latex, pdfbox

For my Java project I need to list all named destinations of a PDF page.

The PDF and its named destination are created with LaTeX (using the [hypertarget command](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks#Hyperlink_and_Hypertarget)), e.g. as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{myImportantString}{}   % the anchor/named destination to be extracted "myImportantString"

Empty example page

\end{document}
```

How do I extract all named destinations of a specific page of this PDF document with the PDFBox library version 2.0.11?

I could not find any working code for this problem in the internet or the PDFBox [examples](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/). This is my current (minified) code:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotation;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class ExtractNamedDests {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            int c = 1;
            PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("<path to PDF file>"));

            for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
                System.out.println("Page " + c + ":");

                // named destinations seem to be no type of annotations since the list is always empty:
                List<PDAnnotation> annotations = page.getAnnotations();
                System.out.println("    Count annotations: " + annotations.size());

                // How to extract named destinations??
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In this example I want to extract the String "myImportantString" from the page in Java.

**EDIT:** Here is the [example PDF file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zwm73y9rhrj1hf3/testfile.pdf?dl=0). I use PDFBox version 2.0.11.

Comment: Please tell what PDFBox version you are using and please share your PDF. In the meantime have a look at doc.getDocumentCatalog().getNames() and getDests().

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I attached a link to an example PDF file with the String "myImportantString" to be extracted. I use version 2.0.11. Thank you, I am currently trying your hint.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thank you very much! Your code gives me a map of all named destinations in the document including "myImportantString"! But the problems is how do I determine to which page the named destination belongs to?

Comment: The link doesn't work. Do you want the page that is the source or the destination of the named destination? For the second, use this: `doc.getPages().indexOf(PDPage)`.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Sorry, I fixed the link. No, I need the source page of the named destination. How do I archive this?

Comment: Your destinations in that PDF don't have a source page. There are no annotations, thus no links.

Comment: If your page had annotations, then I'd search in the link annotations, and there the action or the destination. (One or the other can have a destination)

Comment: Given that you want to extract a string from a named destination, I'm afraid you have a misunderstanding of what a named destination actually is. First, named destinations are not annotations; they are names for a page and set of coordinates for the viewer to go to when executed. The "destination" of a named destination is just a page or a set of coordinates on a page with or without a zoom level. They don't know anything about what content is on that page. Also, named destinations have no source page.. though links can reference a named destination as a target.

Comment: I recommend using PDFDebugger to look at PDFs... it helps getting an understanding of the structures. Note that there are two different views (view menu).

Comment: @TilmanHausherr joelgeraci Thank you both!! I understand named destinations don't work the way I assumed. I will search for another solution replacing the named destinations with some type of linked annotation.

Comment: I looked at that latex link now... \hypertarget is the target, but you should use \hyperlink as well to see if it produces a PDF where you can click on something and it them jumps to a destination.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr My main problem is I need to generate a kind of invisible annotation for certain pages (in a PDF document), such that certain pages can be marked with a unique String. Therefore, the mark must not be visible in the document (for the user). I just need it for my Java program to recognize certain pages by a unique String identifier.
I tried \href, \url, \hyperlink, \hypertarget all with empty body (for invisible mark) but this produces no annotation. These LaTeX commands only produce an annotation if their body is non empty.

Comment: You could use a link annotation with an empty color array, and set the string in the /Contents fields. Or set the annotation flag to invisible.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thank you for your suggestion. I just found out that my original LaTeX command `\hypertarget{myImportantString}{}` with **empty** caption, can be read with the code of your first comment and the the corresponding PDDestination points to the page where the \hypertarget command was defined ("source page")! So the problem is nearly solved :) Thank you! Now, I only have to find out why document.getDocumentCatalog().getNames().getDests(). **getNames()** returns Null for my "production" PDF. I will try your suggestion PDFDebugger or else post a new question here..

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I seems that my named destinations respectively \hypertarget marks in the "production" PDF are nested deep in the document. Do you know how modify your code to recursively parse the correct part of the document to find all named destinations in the whole PDF document? [Here's a screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5l10gubvisy6e93/pdfdebug.png?dl=0) of my "production" PDF. Or should I better start a new thread for this question?

Comment: Try getKids() additional to getNames(). With that one you can again look for names and kids. (recursion)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thank you!! getKids() worked, I'll post the recursive code later as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution with the great help of **Tilman Hausherr**. It uses the code he suggested in his comments.

The method `getAllNamedDestinations()` returns a map of all named destinations in the document (not annotations) with name and destination. Named destinations can be deeply nested in the document. Therefore, the method `traverseKids()` recursively finds all nested named destinations.

```
public static Map<String, PDPageDestination> getAllNamedDestinations(PDDocument document){

        Map<String, PDPageDestination> namedDestinations = new HashMap<>(10);

        // get catalog
        PDDocumentCatalog documentCatalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();

        PDDocumentNameDictionary names = documentCatalog.getNames();

        if(names == null)
            return namedDestinations;

        PDDestinationNameTreeNode dests = names.getDests();

        try {
            if (dests.getNames() != null)
                namedDestinations.putAll(dests.getNames());
        } catch (Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }

        List<PDNameTreeNode<PDPageDestination>> kids = dests.getKids();

        traverseKids(kids, namedDestinations);

        return namedDestinations;
    }

private static void traverseKids(List<PDNameTreeNode<PDPageDestination>> kids, Map<String, PDPageDestination> namedDestinations){

    if(kids == null)
        return;

    try {
        for(PDNameTreeNode<PDPageDestination> kid : kids){
            if(kid.getNames() != null){
                try {
                    namedDestinations.putAll(kid.getNames());
                } catch (Exception e){ System.out.println("INFO: Duplicate named destinations in document."); e.printStackTrace(); }
            }

            if (kid.getKids() != null)
                traverseKids(kid.getKids(), namedDestinations);
        }

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is ok, but you could refactor it if you like: use a foreach loop in `traverseKids` because `kids` is a list, and no need to check for null before the recursive call because this is already at the beginning of the method. The `isEmpty()` check isn't needed, if the list is empty the loop will terminate immediately.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Sure, you are correct! Now it's cleaner. I left the initial kids==null check for the case when the method is not called recursively. Thank you for your help!